# Android Google Custom Search : Requested Entity Not Found Error

Tags: android, kotlin, google-custom-search

I want to use Google's Custom Search API to search for images by text entered by the user in the application.

I have done the following :

- Created an API Key from [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/introduction)
- Created a programmable search engine [here](https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/cse/all)
- Enabled billing for my project [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing)

This is an example of a GET request I am making:

> https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_API_KEY&cx=MY_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID&q=SEARCH_TERM&searchType=image

I keep getting:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound"
      }
    ],
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

I am seeing my requests I am making inside my project's Google Cloud Platform APIs and Services window:

[image: Screenshot]

Looking for reasons why this happens, resulted in primarily billing not being enabled (but that is not my case).

Is there any step that I have missed?